# Whitespace when retrieving database row from Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework, whitespace, padding, trim

I am using Entity Framework and I am adding a `User` (`UserName` and `Password`) to a database table. This table has a `UserName` column (`nchar(20)`) and a `Password` column which is hashed (`varchar(50)`).

The problem occurs when I retrieve a User from the database. The username returned is padded with whitespace at the end (until 20 characters have been filled). I have solved this temporarily using the `Trim()` method however this seems impractical considering I need to do this on every column returned from the database.

What is the other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You should **NOT** use the fixed-length types `CHAR(n)` or `NCHAR(n)` for anything longer than maybe 5, 6 characters; they're fine for things like ISO country or currency codes, but for anything else, use the variable-length `VARCHAR(n)` or `NVARCHAR(n)` - those aren't padded with spaces to their defined length - they only store what's really needed. This is **basic database design 101** - it has absolutely ***nothing*** to do with Entity Framework!

Comment: This also happens with varchar(n) column. I have to change all my varchar(n) columns to nvarchar(n) to avoid the whitespaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to convert your column to nvarchar if you want your column to avoid the extra spaces. I personally  don't like to use char(n) columns for values that aren't of fixed length. 
Otherwise you have to continue trimming